# Replace session with IndexedDB or Redis asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core, indexeddb

I have an existing web app ( asp.net core mvc ) which uses sessions variables to store few lists to persist data which we are looking to clean up.

Thinking of using IndexedDb (localstorage client side ) or Redis ( for a server side approach with session outproc ) . Would appreciate and looking forward to have few thoughts shared to decide which would be better in case there needs to be few lists of medium sizes (say 10000 records ) which needs to be persisted across few requests.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it will be better to use Redis rather than using the IndexDDb.The primary reason for that is the browser support for Indexdb is not consistent across all the browsers and also that will bring minimal changes in your application.The ideal solution will be totally to get rid of session variables. There are multiple ways you can achieve that

1) if there is small amount of data that needs to be persisted you can persist that in cookies rather than session variables.

2)Using the tempdata if the data needs to be shared across just multiple 
requests but if the data needs to be shared throughout all the requests then in that case it will not make any difference.

In general the stateless applications are always helpful as then you have the flexibility to scale them without need to worry about how the state is maintained.

Comment: looking to keep light weight and critical user information in session variable and rest of the heavy weight objects/lists which needs to be persisted across request in either of the client side IndexedDB or Serverside store like Redis. Redis seems to be the right fit but the client is inclined towards the other...Also, how tedious can be the code change as it appears to have bit larger js changes . Is there any other cons related to IndexedDB?